# Memory Error While Trying To Import LoRaE220 module on ESP8266

Tags: iot, esp8266, micropython, espressif-idf

I tried to work on ESP8266 from Espressif and to connect to Ebyte Lora module E220-900T22S. I had download micropython version for esp8266 from micropython.org and also manage to install ebyte lora_e220 library.

But when i tested to import the library i got memoryerror issue as seen below picture.

[image: Memory Error as appears on Thonny]

[image]

I just wondering what cause this issue. Any help from IOT gurus ?